# Why is indentation different in editor and terminal with VSCODE?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, indentation

After updating VSCODE to the latest version, the editor and the terminal show different indentation. Following figures present the format of the code in the editor and terminal, respectively.

Code in editor

[image: Code in editor]

Code in terminal

[image: Code in terminal]

How can I keep the same indentation?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is triggered by radian's auto-indent and can be solved by adding following code to the profile of radian.

```r
options(radian.auto_indentation = FALSE)
```